# F#: Testing whether two strings are anagrams

Tags: f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

Here is my code:

```
let areAnagrams (firstString: string) (secondString: string) =
    let countCharacters (someString: string) =
        someString.ToLower().ToCharArray() |> Array.toSeq
                                           |> Seq.countBy (fun eachChar -> eachChar)
                                           |> Seq.sortBy (snd >> (~-))
    countCharacters firstString = countCharacters secondString

let testString1 = "Laity"
let testString2 = "Italy"
printfn "It is %b that %s and %s are anagrams." (areAnagrams testString1 testString2) (testString1) (testString2)
```

This is the output:

> It is false that Laity and Italy are anagrams.

What went wrong? What changes should I make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation of `countCharacters` sorts the tuples just using the second element (the number of occurrences for each character), but if there are multiple characters that appear the same number of times, then the order is not defined.

If you run the `countCharacters` function on your two samples, you can see the problem:

```
> countCharacters "Laity";;
val it : seq<char * int> = seq [('l', 1); ('a', 1); ('i', 1); ('t', 1); ...]
> countCharacters "Italy";;
val it : seq<char * int> = seq [('i', 1); ('t', 1); ('a', 1); ('l', 1); ...]
```

One solution is to just use `Seq.sort` and sort the tuples using both the letter code and the number of occurrences.

The other problem is that you are comparing two `seq<_>` values and this does not use structural comparison, so you'll need to turn the result into a list or an array (something that is fully evaluated):

```
let countCharacters (someString: string) =
    someString.ToLower().ToCharArray() 
    |> Seq.countBy (fun eachChar -> eachChar)
    |> Seq.sort
    |> List.ofSeq
```

Note that you do not actually need `Seq.countBy` - because if you just sort all the characters, it will work equally well (the repeated characters will just be one after another). So you could use just:

```
let countCharacters (someString: string) =
    someString.ToLower() |> Seq.sort |> List.ofSeq
```

Comment: I think there's an additional issue, which is that equality testing on `seq`s isn't structural.

Comment: @kvb Yeah, I just realized that too :) Added!

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the characters of the two strings gives you an easy solution but this could be a good example of recursion.

You can immediately exclude strings of different length.

You can also filter out all the occurrences of a char per iteration, by replacing them with an empty string.

```
let rec areAnagram (x:string) (y:string) =
    if x.Lenght  <> t.Lenght 
    then false else
    if x.Lenght = 0
    then true else 
    let reply = x.[0].ToString ()
    areAnagram
        (x.Replace (reply,""))
        (y.Replace (reply,""))
```

The above should be faster than sorting for many use cases.

Anyway we can go further and transform it into a fast Integer Sorting without recursion and string replacements

```
let inline charToInt c = 
    int c - int '0'
let singlePassAnagram (x:string) =
    let hash : int array = Array.zeroCreate 100
    x |> Seq.iter (fun c->
    hash.[charToInt c] <- (hash.[charToInt c]+1)
    )  
let areAnagramsFast 
        (x:string) (y:string) =
    if x.Length <> y.Length
    then false else
    (singlePassAnagram x) = 
        (singlePassAnagram y)
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ATLfrb)